# How to access the value of ion options in ion-select multiple

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4

I am trying to use ion-select multiple to get selected value and its string..

previously i tried this using ion-checkbox and worked

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let day of alarm.alarmDays">
        <ion-label>{{day.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="day.value"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

however when i tried the following it didnt work wonders..

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Days</ion-label>
     <ion-select multiple="true" >  
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let day of alarm.alarmDays" name="day.name" [(ngModel)]="day.value">{{day.name}}</ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

This error came

```
ERROR CONTEXT
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

here is the object

```
alarm: Alarm = {
    alarmEnabled: true,
    alarmCreatedBy: "",
    alarmTitle: "",
    alarmTime: "",
    alarmDays:  [
         {
            name: 'Monday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Tuesday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Wednesday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Thursday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Friday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Saturday',
            value: false,
         },
         {
            name: 'Sunday',
            value: false,
         },
       ]
    };
```

iam hopping to be able to retrieve both the value and string from the ion-select multiple, and i wish to see minimum efforts in correcting my english unless you truely dont understand...

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari thx but it still gave the same error as the above

Comment: you have issue with ng-model

Comment: now that i removed the ngmodel input i could not get the values to firebase any ideas? [https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-ion-select-multiple-selected-value-to-firebase/162125]

Answer (score 1):

In html(home page) :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of testData">
        <ion-label>{{x.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [checked]="x.value" ></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>


<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select multiple="true">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let x of testData" [selected]="x.value"> {{x.name}} </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

In component(home page) :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public testData;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.testData = [
      {
        name: "a", 
        value: true
      }, 
      {
        name: "b", 
        value: true
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Running demo : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bk6usm?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: i face similar issue which resolve assigning in component

Comment: first method did still gave the same errors `ERROR CONTEXT`
 and `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` still working around what the second code is trying

Comment: first method because of model. you have declare property in component then only  not throught that error

Comment: i couldnt access alarmDays in your second method... it says name alarmDays not found

Comment: take your alarmday i did dummi

Comment: iam sorry i could not quite catch what you mean. on the first method how did you assigned in component, the second one changes a lot of things i dont understand.

Comment: can you check demo

Comment: stackblitz is blank grey page... i dont think i cant access that website at the moment from where iam from... ill try this later please bear with me

Comment: i did with checkbox. now i am doing with select.

Comment: the checkbox works though... iam only having trouble with select

Comment: i still couldnt access stack blitz... is there an extension i should disable? iam on chrome

Comment: there is no errors in your code thanks. it seems the ngModel was the one causing it after i compared our codes... but i dont know how iam gonna pass that value to firebase without ngmodel.. ill try to find a work around this before i choose your answer